# Remove everything before and after a string part in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to get Amazon product ASIN from the URL here are some examples:

```
https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Flagship-Lenovo-Processor-Bluetooth/dp/B07H15QHT6/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1537733386&sr=1-2-spons&keywords=laptop&psc=1


https://www.amazon.com/Youve-Got-Crabs-Creators-Exploding/dp/B07BKLT9B5/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1537733019&sr=8-1-spons&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=games&psc=1
```

I want to get that text after `/dp/` and remove everything after that text like this

```
B07BKLT9B5 and B07H15QHT6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
split("dp")
```

And get 2 part or use `substring()` and `indexOf()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
public String getCode(String s) {
    int pos = s.indexOf("/dp/"); // find the position of the string "/dp/" in the url
    String substr = s.substring(pos + "/dp/".length()); // get everyting after dp
    String[] parts = substr.split("/"); // split at every '/' character
    return parts[0]; // your result will be the first element of the array
}
```